# Javascript-CSS Show and Hide form elements

Tags: javascript, css, cakephp-1.3

By using Javascript how to show and hide some parts of the table(Eg: TR or TD). This should work depending on the data fetched from the Database
I am using CakePHP framework for my Application and using a single view file for Add and Edit.
In Edit mode - Depending on the data fetched, I need to show and hide some parts of the form elements.

Scenario
There are five questions A,B,C,D nad E
B is dependent on A, C is dependent on B, D is dependent on C and E is dependent on D
So while adding I have hidden B,C,D and E
on selecting of the respective questions the other questions will be displayed.
A,B,C,D - All are "Yes/No"(radio buttons) questions.

Eg:

```
<'table>
<'tr id='a'>
  <'td colspan='2'>A<'/td>
<'/tr>  
<'tr id='b'>
  <'td colspan='2'>B<'/td>
<'/tr>
<'tr id='cd'>
  <'td id='c'>C<'/td><'td id='d'>D<'/td>
<'/tr>
<'/table>
```

(' Prefix for all HTML tags)

How can I do it. Please post your comments.

Comment: Thanks Richard,RobG,M.Azad for your swift response. I can understand the CSS properties and how to do the same by JS. I am not sure that have explained you properly. If not excuse me. Let me try to explain in detail. My question is  
I am using a single page for ADD and EDIT. Add page functionality works fine and have implemented by the way you guys explained above.

Comment: continuation .. 
Assume the following steps in add functionality
1. Select yes for Question A
2. Select yes for Question B
3. Select no for Question C
continuation ....
In the Edit mode (same page), it should show the question A,B,C and hide D. But this is dynamic for each and every record. So far I haven't implemented for edit mode (That is a Question here). So in edit mode, I can see only question "A". Right now, all other fields are hidden which is executing like add page.

Comment: continuation .. The solution should be:
1. First we need to differentiate add and edit page.
2. If add. show and hide the respective fields - which will be hard coded
3. If edit, how to show and hide the respective fields which is dynamic and based on the DB record-set? (There are few ways to implement in my mind. But looking for the optimized way. So please put yours comments and thoughts)  

Hope this make sense..... :)

Answer (score 16):

CSS has two special attributes, the first one is `display` and the second is `visibility`.

## display

Has many properties or values, but the ones we need are `none` and `block`. `none` is like a hide value, and `block` is like show. If you use the `none` value you will totally hide what ever HTML tag you have applied this CSS style. If you use `block` you will see the HTML tag and its content.

## visibility

Has many values, but we want to know more about the `hidden` and `visible` values. `hidden` will work in the same way as the `block` value for display, but this will hide tag and its content, but it will not hide the physical space of that tag.

For example, if you have a couple of text lines, then and image (picture) and then a table with three columns and two rows with icons and text. Now if you apply the `visibility` CSS with the `hidden` value to the image, the image will disappear but the space the image was using will remain in its place. In other words, you will end with a big space (hole) between the text and the table. Now if you use the `visible` value your target tag and its elements will be visible again.

Then you can change them via JavaScript for `display`:

```
document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
```

for `visibility`:

```
document.getElementById(id).style.visibility= "hidden";
document.getElementById(id).style.visibility= "visible";
```

So you can create a function that does this, and then reference that function when they select the correct answer.
It depends how they select it to how you would make it show.

Otherwise if this isn't what you want the innerHTML function could also work.

Comment: For display, don't use 'block' to display the element again since the display property can have many different values (in particular, TR and TD have different default display values in different browsers). Instead, use '' (empty string) so it returns to its default or inherited value.

Answer (score 2):

To hide an element but keep its place within the document flow (i.e. hiding it will not cause other elements to move up and fill its space), set its `style.visibility` property to "hidden". To show it again, set it to "visible".

e.g.

```
var el = document.getElementById('a');
a.style.visibility = 'hidden';
a.style.visibility = 'visible';
```

To hide an element and remove it from the flow (i.e. it will be as if it wasn't in the document, other elements will fill its place) set its `style.display` property to "none". To show it again (and cause a re-flow of the document because now the element will take up space again) set it to "" (empty string).

```
var el = document.getElementById('a');
a.style.display = 'none';
a.style.display = '';
```

That last bit is extremely important as it allows the element to return to its default or inherited display value, which could be any one of a number of values (and might even be different to when it was hidden).

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jQuery it's easy: `("#b").css("display","none");` or `("#b").css("display","block");`

If you don't use jQuery check out this [quirksmode.org article](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/changess.html#).

Answer (score 0):

to add to what M. Azad wrote, if you're using jQuery, the easier way to hide/show something is to use hide(), show(), or toggle(), like this:
`("#b").hide();  or ("#b").show(); or ("#b").toggle();`

toggle() will hide a visible element, or show a hidden element. These functions also have animation features. You can read about them here: http://api.jquery.com/hide/

jQuery is one terrific library. Many stackoverflow readers are well-acquainted with it, I'm sure, but for those who aren't, it's well worth studying, and their online documentation is terrific.